# Order array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hey guys. Should be simple, couldn't find a proper answer on other questions because mine is slightly different.

I have an array, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 21
            [quality] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 20
            [quality] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 19
            [quality] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 18
            [quality] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 17
            [quality] => 3
        )

)
```

I need to be able to **order** the array by highest to lowest (regarding the `quality` key) in ascending order or descending (when a mode has been selected), so for example I need it to order an array and return it ordered, e.g.

```
function order_array($array, $order = 'asc')
{
   if($order == 'asc')
   // order the array from lowest to highest

   if($order == 'desc')
   // order the array from highest to lowest
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

Comment: But will this let me order by ascending or descending?

Comment: This will order DESC, to get a ASC order just change  return ($b < $a) ? -1 : 1;

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `usort`:

```
usort($array, "my_custom_sort_function");
function my_custom_sort_function($a, $b) {
    return $a['quality'] - $b['quality'];
}
```